# Print $scope value in template

Tags: angularjs

I have this function:

```
$scope.bigCurrentPage = 1;
$scope.maxSize = 5;
$scope.bigTotalItems = 175;
$scope.currentPage = 1;
$scope.numPages=function() {
    $scope.totalPages=$scope.all.length;
};
```

I want to print $scope.totalPages in my temp.view.html and I try to do it like this

```
<ul uib-pagination total-items="bigTotalItems" ng-model="bigCurrentPage"
    max-size="maxSize" class="pagination-sm">
</ul>
<pre>Page: {{bigCurrentPage}} / {{totalPages}}</pre>
```

But I get output: 
`Page: 1/` , `{{totalPages}} doesn't get printed out. Why?

Comment: You probably don't call $scope.numPages function which causes $scope.totalPages being undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either call the function once before using value .

`$scope.numPages=function() {
    $scope.totalPages=$scope.all.length;
};
$scope.numPages();`

Now 
`<pre>Page: {{bigCurrentPage}} / {{totalPages}}</pre>` this will work.

But, in this approach you need to call `$scope.numPages();`
 everytime the value of `$scope.all.length` is changed to keep the value of `totalPages` updated.

**OR**

Modify the function, here you don't need to worry about change in the value of `$scope.all.length`, the `totalPages` will get updated automatically in view.

`$scope.numPages=function() {
    return $scope.all.length;
};`

and use `numPages()` directly

`<pre>Page: {{bigCurrentPage}} / {{ numPages() }}</pre>`

Answer (score 0):

You likely need to actually execute the function.  So far all you've done is declared your function, but not really called it.  Because of that, $scope.totalPages doesn't really exist until then.

So it'd be like this:

```
$scope.bigCurrentPage = 1;
    $scope.maxSize = 5;
    $scope.bigTotalItems = 175;
    $scope.currentPage = 1;
$scope.numPages=function(){
        $scope.totalPages=$scope.all.length;
    };
$scope.numPages();
```

Though, this will only work assuming you have an array declared somewhere as `$scope.all`

Answer (score 0):

Just use `{{all.length || 0}}` in the view .... not sure why you need a function for this